# Do maps with list keys form a monad?

Tags: haskell, typeclass-laws

Consider the following type constructor:

```
newtype Mapnad k v = Mapnad { runMapnad :: Map [k] v }
```

Since `Ord k => Ord [k]` (lexicographical order), we can reuse the functor instance for maps for this type in an obvious way:

```
deriving instance Ord k => Functor (Mapnad k)
```

Furthermore, it seems as though `Ord k => Monad (Mapnad k)`, according to the following scheme:

```
-- For readability
type (×) = (,)
infixr ×

toList'   :: Ord k => Mapnad k v -> [[k] × v]
fromList' :: Ord k => [[k] × v] -> Mapnad k v

return' :: Ord k => a -> Mapnad k a
return' = fromList' . return . return

join' :: Ord k => Mapnad k (Mapnad k v) -> Mapnad k v
join' =
  fmap toList'        -- Mapnad k [[k] × v]
  >>> toList'         -- [[k] × [[k] × v]]
  >>> (=<<) sequenceA -- [[k] × [k] × v]
  >>> fmap join       -- [[k] × v]
  >>> fromList'       -- Mapnad k v

-- Note: we are using the writer monad for tuples above

instance Ord k => Applicative (Mapnad k)
  where
  pure = return
  (<*>) = ap

instance Ord k => Monad (Mapnad k)
  where
  return = return'
  ma >>= amb = join' $ fmap amb ma
```

Is this a legal monad instance? QuickCheck seems to suggest so, but it'd be good to know for sure one way or the other.

---

Bonus question: Assuming this is indeed a monad, are there any monoids `k` besides the free `[a]` monoid for which `Map k` is a monad? There are certainly counterexamples: i.e. monoids `k` for which `Map k` is *not* a monad. For instance, with the same monad instance for `Map (Sum Int)`, QuickCheck finds a counterexample to the associativity law.

```
-- m >>= (\x -> k x >>= h) == m >>= k >>= h
m :: { 0 -> 0; 3 -> 7 }
k :: \x -> if (odd x) then { -3 -> 1 } else { 0 -> 0 }
h :: \x -> if (odd x) then { }         else { 0 -> 0 }
```

Comment: A `Map` is just like a function, so it should be easy to make it a modified version of a `Reader` monad. In your example, it looks like you are reimplementing `ListT (Writer k) v`.

Comment: @Krantz Could you write out the instances you're referring to? I can't see how a `Map` is just like a function, at least not without changes to the notion of a function like imposing bounds on the domain and partializing the codomain. Regarding `ListT`, which definition of `ListT` are you referring to?

Comment: @duplode `type Map k v = k -> Maybe v` which is `ReaderT k Maybe v`, so semantically there is a legit monad instance. Probably not very useful, though - `return` produces an infinite map, and `join` diagonalises a 2D map. Not really an API which most bread-and-butter `Data.Map` users will be clamouring for!

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson You're right, I let myself get carried away with a flawed analogy. Half of this instance even exists as [the `Bind` instance for `Map` in *semigroupoids*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroupoids-5.3.4/docs/src/Data.Functor.Bind.Class.html#line-673).

Comment: `ContT r (Map k)` surprisingly is a monad, and can do something kind of similar to what you're talking about here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not a monad. We can adapt your counterexample for `Sum`; the key property is that `3 <> -3 = 0 = 0 <> 0`, which introduces a choice point for the value that `0` maps to in `m >>= k`. We can choose, e.g., `"" <> "a" = "a" <> ""` to set up the same choice. So:

```
m = { "" -> 0; "a" -> 7 }
k x = if odd x then { "" -> 1 } else { "a" -> 0 }
h x = if odd x then { }         else { ""  -> 0 }
```

Then I observe:

```
m >>= k >>= h           = { }
m >>= (\x -> k x >>= h) = { "a" -> 0 }
```

Every non-trivial monoid has such choice points. The associativity property of monoids says:

```
a <> (b <> c) = (a <> b) <> c
```

So you are in trouble if there are any `a` and `b` for which `a /= a <> b`.

(It *is* a monad if you choose the trivial monoid: specifically, it is (monad-isomorphic to) `Maybe`.)

Comment: I've been mulling over the "So you are in trouble if ..." bit and I have to admit I don't really understand why this is fatal for associativity. I do understand that you can introduce duplicate keys when `join`-ing, one of which then needs to be dropped, but why non-associativity necessarily follows from this I don't quite understand.

Comment: E.g. suppose I forget about the back and forth conversion to a `Map` and merely work with the `[([k], v)]` representation (allowing duplicates). Then the associativity law demands that `join . join = join . fmap join`, and on `{ "": { "a": { "": 0 } }, "a": { "": {} } }` I think both routes give us `{ "a": 0 }`, provided we are patient and don't throw stuff away. Maybe this is better suited for a different question though.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin There are values where your `join` has no choice but to throw information away. Consider `{ "": { "a": 0 }, "a": { "": 1 }}`. The obvious things for `join` to return are `{ "a": 0 }` or `{ "a": 1 }`, but either choice throws some information away. (And this information loss can be exploited to break associativity.)

Comment: As far as I understand you'd just end up with `{ "a": 0, "a": 1 }`. I'm explicitly removing `Map` from the equation and working directly with the `[([k], v)]` representation, which does not have the restriction that a key may have at most one value.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin `Map [k] [v]` has a chance of being a monad in a way similar to what you described in your question. I haven't worked out the details.

Comment: "I'm explicitly removing Map from the equation and working directly with the `[([k],v)]` representation" - that's `WriterT [k] [] v`, so yeah it's a monad. `Map k v` is not isomorphic to `[(k,v)]` though.